# Hiding elements of HTML in android internet browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom

I am working on a test project targeting android internet browser. I am hiding some object onLoad using javascript.

The problem is, that it is working in mozilla firefox but not working in android default internet browser.

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" async>

function ajaxpath_59c479660b217(url){return window.location.href == '' ? url : url.replace('&s=','&s=' + escape(window.location.href));}(function(){document.write('<div id="fcs_div_59c479660b217"></div>');fcs_59c479660b217=document.createElement('script');fcs_59c479660b217.type="text/javascript";fcs_59c479660b217.src=ajaxpath_59c479660b217((document.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:")+"//www.freecommentscript.com/GetComments2.php?p=59c479660b217&s=#!59c479660b217");setTimeout("document.getElementById('fcs_div_59c479660b217').appendChild(fcs_59c479660b217)",1);})();

    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("comment-ad").style.display = "none";
}

function myFunction2() // no ';' here
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("fcs_Comment_59c479660b217");
    if (elem.value=="Enter your comment here") elem.value = "Enter your post here";
    else elem.value = "Enter your post here";
}

function myFunction3() // no ';' here
{
        document.getElementById("comment-rss-feed").style.display = "none";

}

function showFilterItem() {
    if (filterstatus == 0) {
        filterstatus = 1;
        $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().showFilterItem();
        document.getElementByClassName("ShowButton").innerHTML = "Hide Filter";
    }
    else {
        filterstatus = 0;
        $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().hideFilterItem();
        document.getElementById("ShowButton").innerHTML = "Show filter";
    }
}


if (document.readyState === "complete") {
   myFunction();
   myFunction2();
   myFunction3();
   showFilterItem();
}
else {
   window.onload = function () {
      myFunction();
      myFunction2();
      myFunction3();
      showFilterItem();
   };
};

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the script added before the HTML elements you want to hide, or after them?

Comment: I am just using the script I provided nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I'll put the whole script in domloaded event to be sure that js can find the dom elements. like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
function ajaxpath_59c479660b217(url){return window.location.href == '' ? url : url.replace('&s=','&s=' + escape(window.location.href));}(function(){document.write('<div id="fcs_div_59c479660b217"></div>');fcs_59c479660b217=document.createElement('script');fcs_59c479660b217.type="text/javascript";fcs_59c479660b217.src=ajaxpath_59c479660b217((document.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:")+"//www.freecommentscript.com/GetComments2.php?p=59c479660b217&s=#!59c479660b217");setTimeout("document.getElementById('fcs_div_59c479660b217').appendChild(fcs_59c479660b217)",1);})();

    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("comment-ad").style.display = "none";
}

function myFunction2() // no ';' here
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("fcs_Comment_59c479660b217");
    if (elem.value=="Enter your comment here") elem.value = "Enter your post here";
    else elem.value = "Enter your post here";
}

function myFunction3() // no ';' here
{
        document.getElementById("comment-rss-feed").style.display = "none";

}

function showFilterItem() {
    if (filterstatus == 0) {
        filterstatus = 1;
        $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().showFilterItem();
        document.getElementByClassName("ShowButton").innerHTML = "Hide Filter";
    }
    else {
        filterstatus = 0;
        $find('<%=FileAdminRadGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().hideFilterItem();
        document.getElementById("ShowButton").innerHTML = "Show filter";
    }
}


if (document.readyState === "complete") {
   myFunction();
   myFunction2();
   myFunction3();
   showFilterItem();
}
else {
   window.onload = function () {
      myFunction();
      myFunction2();
      myFunction3();
      showFilterItem();
   };
};
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am new with DOM. Can you please give an example of what you're suggesting if possible?

Comment: When you try to handle some DOM-Elements in your script (i.e. document.getElementByID('xxx')) - Javascript have to find this Element in order to execute the code relating to it. Problems will occure if the Javascript can't find this element (because it's not ready rendered in the dom). In order to fix that, you can use the Event listener in my post, just to make sure all the DOM elements are loaded and accessible for the javascript